# Qt TableView indexAt different behaviour with/without header

Tags: python, pyside, qtableview

Using PySide 1.2

Grabbing the index of a clicked item in a `QTableView` returns a different result wether there is a horizontal header or not.
If there is a horizontal header, it's seems to be included in the computing of `visualRect`. So the first line, first column index is no longer 0, 0 but 1, 0.

Is this intended ? Because it is really confusing and inconvenient because the last line index will be invalid.

To reproduce :

```
import re
import operator
import os
import sys 
# from Qt.QtCore import * 
# from Qt.QtGui import * 
# from Qt.QtWidgets import * 
from PySide.QtCore import * 
from PySide.QtGui import * 


def main(): 
    app = QApplication(sys.argv) 
    w = MyWindow() 
    w.show() 
    sys.exit(app.exec_()) 


class CustomTableView(QTableView):
    """
    """

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        """
        """
        super(CustomTableView, self).__init__(parent=parent)

    def mousePressEvent(self, mouse_event):
        """
        """
        view_pos = self.mapFromGlobal(mouse_event.globalPos())
        index = self.indexAt(view_pos)
        print('mouse press index not  cutting header : ' + str((index.row(), index.column())))
        view_pos.setY(view_pos.y() - self.horizontalHeader().sizeHint().height())
        index = self.indexAt(view_pos)
        print('mouse press index cutting header : ' + str((index.row(), index.column())))
        super(CustomTableView, self).mousePressEvent(mouse_event)


class MyWindow(QWidget): 
    def __init__(self, *args): 
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args) 

        # create table
        self.get_table_data()
        table = self.createTable() 

        # layout
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(table) 
        self.setLayout(layout) 

    def get_table_data(self):
        stdouterr = os.popen4("dir c:\\")[1].read()
        lines = stdouterr.splitlines()
        lines = lines[5:]
        lines = lines[:-2]
        self.tabledata = [re.split(r"\s+", line, 4)
                     for line in lines]

    def createTable(self):
        # create the view
        tv = CustomTableView()

        # set the table model
        header = ['date', 'time', '', 'size', 'filename']
        tm = MyTableModel(self.tabledata, header, self) 
        tv.setModel(tm)
        return tv

class MyTableModel(QAbstractTableModel): 
    def __init__(self, datain, headerdata, parent=None, *args): 
        """ datain: a list of lists
            headerdata: a list of strings
        """
        QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent, *args) 
        self.arraydata = datain
        self.headerdata = headerdata

    def rowCount(self, parent): 
        return len(self.arraydata)

    def columnCount(self, parent): 
        return len(self.arraydata[0]) 

    def data(self, index, role): 
        if not index.isValid(): 
            return None 
        elif role != Qt.DisplayRole: 
            return None 
        return self.arraydata[index.row()][index.column()]

    def headerData(self, col, orientation, role):
        if orientation == Qt.Horizontal and role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self.headerdata[col]
        return None

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have to use the global position and then pass it to the local position since you will get the position with respect to the upper corner of the QTableView, but indexAt requires the position with respect to the content according to the [docs](https://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QAbstractItemView.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QAbstractItemView.indexAt):

> **PySide.QtGui.QAbstractItemView.indexAt(point)**
>
> Parameters:   point – PySide.QtCore.QPoint
>
> Return type:  PySide.QtCore.QModelIndex
>
> Returns the model index of the item at the `viewport coordinates point`.

You must use the position of the event: `mouse_event.pos()`

```
def mousePressEvent(self, mouse_event):
    index = self.indexAt(mouse_event.pos())
    print('mouse press index: ' + str((index.row(), index.column())))
    super(CustomTableView, self).mousePressEvent(mouse_event)
```

If you want to use the global position then you must convert it to a local position with respect to the `viewport()`:

```
def mousePressEvent(self, mouse_event):
    view_pos = self.viewport().mapFromGlobal(mouse_event.globalPos())
    index = self.indexAt(view_pos)
    print('mouse press index : ' + str((index.row(), index.column())))
    super(CustomTableView, self).mousePressEvent(mouse_event)
```